# about PHP configure:--with-zlib=DIR and --with-zlib-dir=DIR

Tags: php

from ./configure --help:

> --with-zlib=DIR    Include ZLIB support (requires zlib >= 1.0.9)
>
> --with-zlib-dir=`<DIR>`    Define the location of zlib install directory

first one: Why "--with-zlib" need a DIR ?

second one: does "Define the location of zlib install directory
" mean "Define the location of directory of zlib which you have already installed in system" ?

what's the difference between "--with-zlib" and "--with-zlib-dir" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first I think that you only have browsed the first part of `./confiure --help` , because you may wonder when you figure out that:

```
hassan@hassan:/php/php-src$ ./configure --help | grep "zlib"
  --with-zlib=DIR         Include ZLIB support (requires zlib >= 1.0.9)
  --with-zlib-dir=<DIR>   Define the location of zlib install directory
  --with-zlib-dir=DIR     GD: Set the path to libz install prefix
  --with-zlib-dir=DIR     PDO_MySQL: Set the path to libz install prefix
  --with-zlib-dir=DIR     ZIP: Set the path to libz install prefix
  --with-zlib-dir=DIR     mysqlnd: Set the path to libz install prefix
```

so, **`--with-zlib[=DIR]`** is coming when you are willing to compile the [**`zlib`**](http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php) extension :

> Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default. You will need to
>   configure PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]

otherwise **`--with-zlib-dir`** is used when you want to compile another extension which is need zlib , for example, when are you trying to compile [PDO Mysql Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php#ref.pdo-mysql.installation) from source :

> Optionally, the --with-zlib-dir[=DIR] is used to set the path to the
>   libz install prefix.